# abort all active request before sending another request for same url in backbone collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

i am making search request Consider this:

User Enters "Filter A" for an activity stream.
A collection's url changes to represent the filter
collection.fetch is called
User quickly Enters "Filter B" before the xhr for "Filter A" returns to reset the collection.
"Filter B" returns from the server, collection.reset is called automatically for "Filter B"
"Filter A" finally returns (after "Filter B") and resets the collection to "Filter A".
The app is now in the wrong state.

How do I abort Previous pending request.

```
self.collection = new searchCollection();
self.collection.fetch({
    timeout : 60000,
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
      "searchString" : searchKey
    },
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {},
    success : function(result) {},
    error : function(xhr, status, error) {}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintain a variable to save the fetch request.

```
self.fetchXhr = self.collection.fetch();
```

Before placing any fetch request, check whether the variable has valid and ongoing request.

```
if(self.fetchXhr != undefined && self.fetchXhr.readyState > 0 && self.fetchXhr.readyState < 4)
   self.fetchXhr.abort();
```

Comment: Learned. Also nice idea to use it like this. Thank you.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest has 5 readyState values: 0 - The request is not initialized, 1 - The request is set up, 2 - The request has been sent, 3 - The request is in process, 4 - The request has been completed. The readyState value of 1-3, indicates the request is a active one.

Comment: but there is problem aborting a request calling error block that further i need to handle